# ValueError: incomplete format

Tags: python

I'm trying to take two PDF documents, remove the first page from doc1 and add page 1 from doc2.  I think I have the code mostly where it needs to be, but I'm receiving "ValueError: incomplete format."  Here is the code I have, and the error it's giving me is for the third to last line.

```
import os, shutil, sys, PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

origList = list()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\pytest\orig'):
    for file in files:
            origList.append(file)
print "Original PDF list:"
print origList

stampList = list()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\pytest\stamp'):
    for file in files:
            stampList.append(file)
print "Stamped PDF List:"
print stampList

oX = 0
output = PdfFileWriter()
for document in origList:
    file1 = PdfFileReader(open(r'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\pytest\orig\%s' %origList[oX], "rb"))
    file2 = PdfFileReader(open(r'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\pytest\stamp\%s' %stampList[oX], "rb"))
    file1.decrypt("")
    curFile = origList[oX]
    output.addPage(file2.getPage(0))
    file2Pages = file2.getNumPages()
    file2Counter = 1
    while file2Counter <= file2Pages:
        output.addPage(file1.getPage(file2Counter))
        file2Counter = file2Counter + 1
    outputStream = file(r'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\pytest\output\%' %curFile, "wb")
    output.write(outputStream)
    oX = oX + 1
```

The line the error is for is:

```
outputStream = file(r'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\pytest\output\%' %curFile, "wb")
```

I followed the examples given with the module, and I thought that was how it should be written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line that gives the error, you're missing the format specifier, i.e.

```
outputStream = file(r'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\pytest\output\%' %curFile, "wb")
                                                            ^
         # what type are we formatting? Need to add an 's' here for 'string'
```

Compare to a previous line...

```
file1 = PdfFileReader(open(r'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\pytest\orig\%s' %origList[oX], "rb"))
                                                                 ^
                              # the output line is missing this 's'
```

Comment: Does it matter if the format specifier is part of the variable being inputted?  The variable itself is "123456.pdf" and when I did try it directly, I received an error that the string object is not callable.

Comment: Look at the lines you use to open the pdf files. You have a `%s` at the end of the path, the `s` specifically saying to "format the variable as a string and put it here". You need the same `s` at the end of this path as well.

Comment: In defining curFile as the variable from above, shouldn't that make it the same?  Even when I change it to the same variable I receive the same str callable object error.

Comment: It's not curFile that is the problem, it's the string formatting specifier, see edit

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, but I'm still getting the str error... outputStream = (open(r'C:\Users\GOlson\Desktop\pytest\orig\%s' %origList[oX], "rb"))

Comment: That's a topic for a new question